# Android: Changing the size of an image in a ListView item

Tags: android, listview

I have this code for a selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Button Focused-->
    <item   android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_background"
            />
<!-- Button Focused Pressed-->
    <item   android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_background"
            />
<!-- Button Pressed-->
    <item   android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default" 
            />
<!-- Button Default Image-->
    <item   android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_background"/>

</selector>
```

And in the activity that uses this selector, I have this:

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/contactsView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchButton"
            android:divider="@color/DarkGoldenrod"
            android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
```

Now this is an example of what a listview item looks like when you click it and hold it down...

[image]

My Question is: Is there anyway I can make that picture smaller and align it to the right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at point 10 of this [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html), get to know how to use your own Layout for a ListView Item and you can do any manipulation you want.

Comment: @some-web thanks for directing me the the relevant section, I am a beginner android programmer and this really helped me out a lot.

Comment: had the same problems when starting, just browse through vogella and the adnroid developers side (by google) and keep on reading and you wil get better and better!

Answer (score 0):

I think that Not the good way to do what you want :) ..
you have To use Costume Array Adapter for that ..

```
public class CustomBookItem extends ArrayAdapter<string>{
ArrayList<string> names;
Context context;
public CustomBookItem(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<string> names )
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId, names);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.names=names;
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v= convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custome_listitem, parent,false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    Textview name=(Textview)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(r.drawbale.icon_search);
    return v;
}
```

R.layout.custome_listitem

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Textview
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```